# How to specify delimiter when reading csv?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to parse csv file. All is fine when there is delimiter ",". But in original file is delimiter ";" And I get error "Undefined offset"

This is my working code with:

```
$CSV = '"id","email",name,google.com,google.com
1,email1@email.com,jack,,+
2,email2@email.com,jack,+,
3,email3@email.com,jack,,';
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b507a90106e22fcba80b9797f5fe704df89db2d1

And this is not working:

```
<?php

$CSV = '"id";"email";name;google.com;google.com
1;email1@email.com;jack;;+
2;email2@email.com;jack;+;
3;email3@email.com;jack;;';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $CSV);

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);

$index = count($csv);
while($index) {
  $columnName = $csv[0][$index];
  $columnNameCount = array_count_values($csv[0])[$columnName];
  $csv[0][$index] = $columnNameCount > 1 ? $csv[0][$index] . "({$columnNameCount})" : $csv[0][$index];
  $index--;

}

array_walk($csv, function (&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});

array_shift($csv);
$select = array_filter($csv, function ($line) {
    return $line['google.com'] == '+';
});

$merges = array_merge($csv, $select); 

foreach ($merges  as $merge) {
  print_r($merge);
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a53bd392f9e01de40ae4b1cb8b1edde30569bff

Comment: Try [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). It's native PHP to parse csv and accepts different delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);
```

You are not passing any extra parameters into `str_getcsv` with this call here, so it will use the default value for all of them.

A small anonymous function that calls `str_getcsv` inside with the extra parameters you want should to the trick:

```
$csv = array_map(function($l) { return str_getcsv($l, ';'); }, $lines);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you tell me why I getting error if I add more rows in my csv file? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/315c9379b1195f86df36102971095b75f2de2dfc if I remove half of the data, everything will be fine

Comment: maybe you can fix my error for my script to work? plese plese please :(

Comment: I don’t even know yet what you actually want to _achieve_ with this script … You have a two-dimensional array in $csv, so I’d maybe start by replacing that while loop with a simple foreach one. What to do inside that loop over the rows then, depends on what you actually want this script to do then.

Comment: I rename duplicate columns with adding a sequence number, then, generate new array. I realized that my cycle is only going on as far as the columns are. but i dont understand how to rewrite my cycle, that he will continue to rename columns, but also with all rows

Comment: You mean duplicate _values_ inside certain column(s)? Please edit your question to include a proper example of what output you expect for a specific sample input.

Comment: I'm afraid my question will be deleted because it won't match the topic. I'll try to describe my code. I want to get an email address, under the column title with the + sign. This is simplest example. If I add more rows than columns I got an error I needt to rename columns because there are coluimns with the same name http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5e6b6c300c294c5928b04698c02697e1106b456

Comment: I don’t understand what you want. If you think this is too different from what you asked here initially, then maybe ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);
```

you apply `str_getcsv` with **default** arguments, second argument by default is `,`. To use `;` you should set it explicitly, for example:

```
$csv = array_map(function($v) { return str_getcsv($v, ';'); }, $lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php
Ex:

```
function csv_to_array($string='', $row_delimiter=PHP_EOL, $delimiter = "," , $enclosure = '"' , $escape = "\\" )
{
    $rows = array_filter(explode($row_delimiter, $string));
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $row = str_getcsv ($row, $delimiter, $enclosure , $escape);

        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }

    return $data;
}
```